# Office.initialize function never called

Tags: ms-office, outlook-web-app

In my outlook 365 app, I have the Office.initialize handler defined, but sometimes the function is never called.  When it isn't called, the app fails to load.  Anyone else run into this and know of the cause?  In this code, the initializing line is called, and the complete sometimes does not.

```
traceService.log("Initializing office addin")
Office.initialize = function () {
        traceService.log("Initialize complete")
        _initialized = true;
    };
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not a solid answer, but it seemed to be something to do with AngularJS.  I'm guessing that when angular loads, it is stomping on some of the office code.  My solution was to rewrite the app (it wasn't that big) using just jquery.  You might be able to get angularjs to late load and get it to work that way.